# using contents of a list as an index in a vector

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list,

```
p1 <- c(1,2,4)
p2 <- c(4,6,5)
p3 <- c(9,2,1)
W <- list(p1,p2,p3)
```

and a vector,

```
a <- c(0.2,0.1,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.4,0.5,0.9)
```

and I want to do the following,

```
v <- c(0,0,0)
for(i in 1:3)
{
  v[i] <- mean(a[W[[i]][]])
}
```

but without the loop.

What's the trick? Lapply?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. What do you want to achieve? Please share your desired output.

Comment: I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rowsum()` with a little work.  This is a loop-less solution that will be very efficient.

```
l <- lengths(W)
rowsum(a[unlist(W)], rep(1:length(W), l)) / l
#        [,1]
# 1 0.3666667
# 2 0.8000000
# 3 0.4000000
```

The only reason I assign `l` here is to avoid the second calculation of `lengths(W)`.  But `lengths()` is also very fast, so you could also do a one-liner as

```
rowsum(a[unlist(W)], rep(1:length(W), lengths(W))) / lengths(W)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to your for loop but use `sapply` to achieve the task.

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) mean(a[W[[i]]]))
# [1] 0.3666667 0.8000000 0.4000000
```

We can also use `tapply`.

```
# Create b based on the index in the list W
index <- unlist(W)
b <- a[index]

# Calcualte the mean for every three numbers
tapply(b, rep(1:3, each = 3), mean)

#         1         2         3 
# 0.3666667 0.8000000 0.4000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your items in a list you can use apply functions without indices.

```
require(purrr)
map_dbl(W, ~mean(a[.]))
# [1] 0.3666667 0.8000000 0.4000000
```

or without `purrr`

```
sapply(W, function(w) mean(a[w]))
# [1] 0.3666667 0.8000000 0.4000000
```